# FFmpeg: Changing output bitrate dynamically

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to encode a video file to an mpeg transport stream (.ts), which is subsequently sent over network. If there is any network bandwidth fluctuation, I want to dynamically change the stream's bitrate.

My current solution involves restarting ffmpeg with a different bitrate as below

```
`ffmpeg -i input.avi -ss <resume point> -b:v <new bitrate> output.ts
```

Unfortunately, for certain i/p file formats, glitches get introduced in the video stream using the above approach. So I am looking for a solution where ffmpeg's output bitrate can be changed dynamically, possibly using signals